# Реализовать функцию преобразования табличных данных

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Реализовать функцию преобразования табличных данных. Входная и выходная таблицы заданы в построчной форме, с помощью списков. Заполненные ячейки имеют строковой тип данных. Пустые ячейки имеют значение None.
Округления производятся стандартно, с помощью функции round.

Над входной таблицей провести ряд преобразований:

1. Удалить пустые столбцы.
2. Преобразовать содержимое ячеек по примерам.
3. Отсортировать строки по столбцу №2 в измененной таблице.

Сделал все пункты, но не понимаю как правильно сортануть

```
def main(inp):
    inp = list(zip(*inp))
    new_inp = []
    for i in inp:
        if i not in new_inp and any(j is not None for j in i):
            new_inp.append(i)
    new_inp = list(zip(*new_inp))
    result = []
    for line in new_inp:
        d = line[0].replace('false', 'Не выполнено')
        name_str = input()
        first_name, last_name = name_str.split()
        name = f'{last_name} {first_name}'
        date_str = input()
        year, month, day = date_str.split('.')
        date = f'{day}/{month}/{year[-2:]}'
        result.append([d, name, date])
    return result
```

Comment: первый ваш вопрос закрыли за отсутствие кода. этот могут закрыть за отсутствие данных и неясную формулировку задания №2. по каким примерам нужно преобразовать содержимое ячеек?

Comment: Да , поторопился не изменил

Comment: Pandas можно использовать или только стандартные библиотеки?

Comment: Только стандартные , да я же по сути все сделал кроме сортировки?